# How to get Rosegarden to work with timidity?

Tags: sound, midi

I'm having problems getting Rosegarden to play midi using Timidity on Ubuntu 11.10 amd64.

I've tried mapping the MIDI playback device to one of the Timidity port that was automatically created on start up and that failed.

I've also tried manually starting timidity using the -iA option, and mapping the Rosegarden's MIDI playback device to one of the new ports, and that still failed.

When I close Rosegarden, I can hear one or two notes get played.

Would anyone know how I can get Rosegarden to work again. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: `chmod 000 /usr/bin/jackd` did the trick for me.